# How can I improve the design and readability of utility algorithms written using java generics?

Tags: java, algorithm

I find that when using java collections, especially when writing utility methods using generics, that my code is often ugly and bloated, full of null checks, nested loops, and repetition.  Focusing on this one example, I'd like ideas for improvement.

Assume we have an `EnumMap` whose values are lists of ratings.  For example, say the `enum`s themselves represent fruit, and each value represents a list ratings given by different people.

```
APPLE  -> [1,   3,   4] 
ORANGE -> [2,   0,   5]

John rated apple 1, Mary rated apple 3, Steve rated apple 4
John rated orange 2, Mary rated orange 0, Steve rated orange 5
Note the specific names are irrelevant and provided only to clarify the setup
```

Now we want to write a utility method that accepts a data structure like the one above, and returns a list of each person's favorite fruit.  Thus the expected result for the above sample data would be: `[ORANGE, APPLE, ORANGE` since `2 > 1`, `3 > 0`, and `5 > 4`.

Below is my current method for doing this.  I'd like an equally (or more) efficient, but cleaner, way to write the same algorithm.

Thanks!

```java
public class MyListUtil {

    public static <K extends Enum<K>, T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> List<K> maxKeysByIndex(EnumMap<K, List<T>> enumMap) {
        Iterator<K> keysIter = enumMap.keySet().iterator();
        int sizeOfAllLists = enumMap.get(keysIter.next()).size();
        List<K> ret = new ArrayList<K>();

        for (int i=0; i<sizeOfAllLists; i++) {
            keysIter = enumMap.keySet().iterator();
            K maxIndexKey = null;
            T maxIndexVal = null;

            while (keysIter.hasNext()){
                K curKey = keysIter.next();
                T curVal = enumMap.get(curKey).get(i);
                if (maxIndexVal == null || curVal.compareTo(maxIndexVal) > 0) {
                    maxIndexVal = curVal;
                    maxIndexKey = curKey;
                }
            }
            ret.add(maxIndexKey);
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: For starters, as for readability, your generic type names don't have to be single letters :-)

Comment: The fact that `T extends Object` is implicit and can thus be omitted.

Comment: Thanks BRPocock, that's a good point

Comment: It is an [express Java convention](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf) to use single letters for generic types. Makes it much easier to read when they stand out from the regular types.

Comment: for-each loops might help significantly, as well as using the `entrySet()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a lot of methods that all operate on the same generic types, I think you could put the helper methods for `K` and `T` into a class, and then only specify the full generic type for the class as a whole.  To use them you would create an object of that class, and then call the methods from it.

The object would be stateless, but it gives you a syntactic way to put all the verbosity into a single place.

```
public class <K extends Enum<K>, T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> MyListUtil {

    public List<K> maxKeysByIndex(EnumMap<K, List<T>> enumMap) {
        ...
    //other methods
}
```

You could try putting the inner loop into a separate method, say:

```
public K getMaxKeyFromPos(EnumMap<K, List<T>> enumMap, int pos)
{
    K maxIndexKey = null;
    T maxIndexVal = null;

    for (K curKey : enumMap.keySet()) {
         T curVal = enumMap.get(curKey).get(pos);
         if (maxIndexVal == null || curVal.compareTo(maxIndexVal) > 0) {
             maxIndexVal = curVal;
             maxIndexKey = curKey;
         }
    }
    return maxIndexKey;
}
```

I've also changed it to `for-each` syntax, removing some of the iterator cruft.

Comment: Edmund, I like the idea of breaking out the inner loop.  It add clarity, but the ugliness has just been moved to a different place.  There must be a design that avoids the null checks altogether, for example.

Comment: The only design that avoids NULLs might be one where you use a standard (possibly third party) function to find the maximum.  But that could involve rearranging your data (basically making a list for each column) before passing it into the function.

Comment: I could, for example, initialize the max values to arbitrary elements, and then run the loop without null checks.  This would do one extra comparison, but the bigger problem is that the code to do the arbitrary initialization is clunky.  In any case, it *can* be avoided, the question is simply, "Is the cure worse than the disease?"

Comment: Or, you could initialise it to the first item, and then iterate only from the second item onwards?  It probably means changing back to a normal `for` loop with iterators and `next` calls though.

Comment: Yeah, that is probably how you'd actually do it, but my point was, as you said, the boilerplate surrounding that and similar methods is worse than the null checks.  It still just seems crazy to me that there isn't a better way.

Answer (score 2):

This is really ugly.

IMO using enums here is wrong. Enums should be programming constants, not people's preferences.

You should create a class PersonFruitPreference that uses a Map to allow the Person to set preferences on fruit. Also add a method getFavoriteFruit()

Comment: The fruit and people's preferences was just a made up example for the clarity of the post.  It's not my real use-case.  The question is about how to write the given algorithm more clearly, not about the appropriateness of the EnumMap<Fruit,List<Integer>> data structure.

Answer (score 1):

First use sortedlist.

Second simply call:

list result;
for(T in enummap) {
  result.add(enummap.get(t).get(0)); //Assume you did a descending sort
}

return result.

Comment: maress, can you please elaborate on your example?  Note that we are not finding the max value of any existing list, but of the lists defined by "all the 0th elements of all the lists," "all the 1th elements of all the lists," etc

Answer (score 1):

A great opportunity to advertise Scala. As you might know, Scala runs on the JVM and is fully compatible to Java bytecode. It gets itself compiled to JVM bytecode.

What isn't apparent from this lean, working code:

```
val apple  = List (1, 3, 4)
val orange = List (2, 0, 5)
val persons = List ("John", "Mary", "Steve") 
val prefs = apple.zip (orange) .zip (persons) 
//  List[((Int, Int), java.lang.String)] = List(((1,2),John), ((3,0),Mary), ((4,5),Steve))
prefs.map (e => e._2 + ": " + (if (e._1._1 > e._1._2) "apple" else "orange"))
// List[java.lang.String] = List(John: orange, Mary: apple, Steve: orange)
```

is, that you have full static compile time safety. But the types get inferred where possible, so you have much less boilerplate.

The first 3 lines produce 3 lists. 
Then they get zipped - in the comment you see, what the type inferrer said he found.

This part is a bit cryptic:

```
 (e => e._2 + ": " + (if (e._1._1
```

Prefs is a List of ((Pair of Int), String), and e is one element in the list. e._2 is the String part (for some reason in such tuples we don't count from 0, but from 1 - I guess, because from where the tuples origin, there was this habit) while lists and arrays and such count from 0 too, like Java.

e._1 is the first part of the element, the pair of Ints, which are the prefs for fruits. e._1._1 for the first, e._1._2 for the second fruit.

After using Scala collections for a while, I don't like Java any more. :) But of course not every company allows to change, and learning it takes a while.